# PHP Debug in Visual Studio Code breaks on every exception

Tags: php, debugging, exception, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am just starting to use the PHP Debug extension in Visual Studio Code (Ubuntu 14.04).  It mostly works fine for me, but I have a problem that every time an exception is thrown, the debugger automatically breaks.  We have lots of exceptions which are internally caught and handled in our code, so I don't want to have to step through each of these.

I've been trying to find something like the [Exception Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx) in Visual Studio 2015, but can't find any equivalent options within Visual Studio *Code*.

php.ini settings:

```
[debug]
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Visual Studio Code launch.json:

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [      
       {
           "name": "Launch currently open script",
           "type": "php",
           "request": "launch",
           "program": "${file}",
           "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
           "port": 9000,
           "args": ["some arguments"]
       }
   ]
}
```

Note that when I use Netbeans for debugging with the same xdebug settings and the same codebase, there is no break-on-exception behaviour, so I think this must be something in Visual Studio Code and/or the PHP Debug extension.

Can anyone suggest how to pass through exceptions without breaking?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've just found the answer myself (feeling a little stupid now!).

In Visual Studio Code, go to View->Debug, then uncheck the 'Everything' button in the Breakpoints section. That option will automatically break on PHP Notices, Warnings and Exceptions.

[image]

Comment: +1 If it makes you feel less s*, I felt s* too... I had to omit the s* word, cause Stack Overflow thought my comment wasn't constructive.

Comment: You should accept your own answer! I feel stupid now for not having seen those options! ;-)

Comment: doh! I missed them too! Thanks for leaving this answer.

Comment: I love you all and thank you and I'm sorry we are all such doofuses lol

Comment: For bonus points I had already left a detailed and embarassing GitHub Issue on the library I was using! Do I win the doofus olympics?

Answer (score 4):

**I was looking for another answer for this question**

I was having breakpoints in my Composer dependencies, which turned debugging really annoying.

For anyone having the same issue, you can set the property `ignore` in the `launch.json` file, with an array of glob patterns for the PHP Debug extension to ignore.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000,
      "ignore": [
        "**/vendor/**/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch currently open script",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 9000,
      "ignore": [
        "**/vendor/**/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. A way to tell Xdebug to ignore exceptions in some directories. Thanks.

Comment: For me it was the `skipFiles` parameter that did the trick. Same array, different parameter.

Answer (score 4):

follow these steps as image below then

check and unchecked what you want

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the breakpoint options mentioned in other answers (notice, warnings, ...) are missing from the breakpoints panel in VSCode you may have attached a second debugger (like chrome) that removed them.  Either attach xdebug last, or by itself.