# Php throw exception Fatal error Uncaught Exception in Visual Studio Code with XDebug

Tags: php, exception

I'm trying to throw an exception inside a try ... catch block but for some reason I get an error
Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception. A handler is assigned, but why doesn't it fire?

```
try {
   if (!isset($_SESSION["Authorized"])){
      throw new Exception();
   } 
} catch (Exception $e){
   die('No access');
}
```

Clarification, I was surprised to find that the error only occurs when debugging Visual Studio code using Xdebug. If debug mode is off, no error occurs. Why so?

Comment: The above code seems to work just fine? https://3v4l.org/acSub

Comment: The error only occurs when debugging in Visual Studio Code. Fixed description

Comment: In result - help this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538157/php-debug-in-visual-studio-code-breaks-on-every-exception

Comment: Why are you using exceptions here at all? Why not just an if-statement? You would get the exact same result: `if (!isset($_SESSION[...])) { die('No access'); }`.

Comment: This code work fine. I checked.